# Ubuntu 23.04: Window with VSCode (and other apps) never starts maximized

Tags: 23.04

It seems to be a regression in 23.04. It worked for me in 22.10. Then I upgraded to 23.04 and the issue arised.

When I start VSCode, its window is never maximized though I maximized it last time before I closed it.
Also other applications (e.g. Skype) are affected.

Is there a new way how to force persistent maximized window of an application in Ubuntu 23.04?

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 on Wayland.

Comment: Reported also here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/2013542